# How to select an image?

Tags: android, android-intent

I just start learning andriod and as far as I just access to the gallery I wanted to select an image from gallery and open that image here is my code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button obj= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    obj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                  startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: ok. and ? did you had a question ?

Comment: yes i wanted to open the selected image

Comment: and you did try something already ? like reading the documentation for Activity ? the section that mentions the startActivityForResult ?

Comment: Refer this example: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/ Hope this helps!

Comment: yes Intent.ACTION_VIEW works fine to open image but same code is not working for andriod 2.3.5